# Angular 6 does not display data retrieved from Asp Net Web API 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

Brief explanation of my problem:

I have an Angular app up and it is running with Asp Net Core Web API 2.2. Generally, this is nothing really complicated, it is mostly CRUD application, the problem also isn’t rocket science issue for more advanced Angular users than me.

Web API is hosted on IIS, with proper Database connection. It is proper because sample data was put to DB, and it is retrieved as can be seen in Postman result.

Although, on client side the data isn’t displayed. Service and component code are below, I have also included console feedback. Table in which data should be display, is generated, even with corresponding number of rows. The only thing is the data missing. I am suspicious about proper JSON format. Just because it is first project of this type in my life, where I combine Angular and .Net, I lack expierience with similar issues and I’d love to receive some hints and help.

Related code:

for Angular service I have:

```
  url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/clients/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getClients(): Observable<Array<Client>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Client>>(this.url );
  }
```

for Component (I call getClients on init)

```
 clients:  Array<Client> ;       
 client: any;             

  getClients() {  
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(data => {
      this.clients = data ;
      console.log(data); 
    });

  }
```

[under and over 'tutaj' word ('here' in polish I try console.log array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX9Dg.jpg)

[matching num of rows in table from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DBre.jpg)

[Postman message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9CdP.jpg)

Comment: what is your code at html side ? you need to set data at html side too properly.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of your network after reloading?

Comment: How are you binding the `this.clients` to your Angular markup? Can you also show what's displayed when you performed the line `console.log(data)`.

Comment: A tip from me: Use [Nsag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) to generate your service

Comment: @Angelo, console.log(data) now shows two arrays  displayed in the following form Array(2) 0: {id: 7...

Comment: @mkvv Can you share the html code for rendering the clients data?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood it is below in my answer

Answer (score 0):

*I've solved it, the problem was indeed in html code. I had some code related to login system which was checking role of logged in user, and it was causing errors.
Thanks for contributions though!*

F. Bekir Yücel, serializing the model doesn't change anything.

```
getClients() {  
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(data => {
      this.clients = data ;
      console.log(data); // this one displays daya
      console.log("Test"); //this also is displayed
      console.log(this.clients[0].Id); // this is undefined
    });
```

Html part looks like this:

```
<td id="id">{{client.cardId}}</td>

<td>
  <div *ngIf="client.id != editRowId">
    <p>{{client.name}}</p>

  </div>
```

and that goes like this till last column.